# Why did Avraham name his son before the Bris (circumcision)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, brit-milah, vayera

Why does the Torah seem to imply that Avraham named his son before the bris?
First:

> וַיִּקְרָא אַבְרָהָם אֶת שֶׁם בְּנוֹ הַנּוֹלַד לוֹ אֲשֶׁר יָלְדָה לּוֹ שָׂרָה יִצְחָק
>
> And Abraham called the name of his son that was born unto him, whom Sarah bore to him, Isaac.

([Gen. 21:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0121.htm#3))

So he called his name Yitzchak, and then the next verse says:

> וַיָּמָל אַבְרָהָם אֶת יִצְחָק בְּנוֹ בֶּן שְׁמֹנַת יָמִים כַּאֲשֶׁר צִוָּה אֹתוֹ אֱ־לֹהִים
>
> And Abraham circumcised his son Isaac when he was eight days old, as God had commanded him.

(21:4)

and then they did the Bris (circumcision).

Isn't our Minhag to do the Bris and then name the child undermined by this case?

Comment: In addition, God Himself dictates a name for Yitzchak way ahead of time and refers to him by that name in [Gen. 17:19-21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#19)

Comment: Did Avraham wear a Streimel?

Comment: @DoubleAA of course he did. The pasuk says (15:5) that God brought him outside, and would Avraham have gone outside without a streimel (chalilah)?!

Comment: R' Joseph Breuer זצ"ל was known to congratulate the parents of newborn sons "masol tauv, what is his name ?"

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find the source of our Minhag to give the name only after the Bris and when it started, but I have an idea of why it is like this:
In the case of Yitzchak the name was already known. Hashem gave it to the newborn even before there was a newborn, so there is no need to postpone it as we do today.

Comment: That's sort of [begging the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question). Isn't this taboo undermined additionally by the fact that God gave Yitzchak his name in [Gen. 17:19-21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#19)?

Answer (score 8):

The reaoson we do not name children until the Bris is based on the fact that Hashem changed Avraham's name in conjunction with his Bris at age 99. In addition, a boy receives the total Neshama at the Bris, and a person cannot be name until attaining that completion. (See Zohar - Lech Lecha 93a, Ta'amei Minhagim 929)

Perhaps, Avraham knew that Yitzchok received his total Neshama at birth and therefore named him immediately.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Mordechai Halperin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Halperin), in "[הקדמת קריאת שם היילוד אשר מילתו מתעכבת עקב מחלה](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52109&pgnum=234)", our *Minhag* of naming the child right after the *Berit Milah* is mentioned neither in the *Talmud*( *Shabbat* 137b) nor in the *Mishneh Torah*( in the beginning of *Hilkhot Milah* Ch. 3).

Moreover, both *Ba'al ha-Itur*( mentioned by the [Tur Yoreh De'ah 265](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&pgnum=400)), and the [Abudraham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abudraham)( in [Seder Berakhot, Ch. 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=188)), in their versions of the *Tefilah* mentioning the son's name, use "שנקרא שמו פלוני"( "that his name **has been** called so-and-so"), denoting that the name has already been given beforehand, as opposed to "ויקרא שמו בישראל"( "and his name **will be** called in Israel"), denoting that the name is yet to be given, that we use today( our's being based on the versions in *Machzor Vitri*, *Sefer ha-Roqach*, *etc.*). Also, neither mention postponing the naming of the child till the *Berit*.

On a side note, the article [mentions the *Pasuq* being asked about](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52109&pgnum=237), and cites as reason to differentiate between the naming of Yitzchaq before his *Berit* and what we do today, that Avraham was commanded as to the naming of his son already before his birth( as rony mentioned in his answer).

Answer (score 4):

(Although this answer contains some of what has been said already, since it comes from the pen of the [Netziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin), and since he grounds his explanation in the language of the posukim, it is very worthwhile to add it here.)

The Netziv [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12896&st=&pgnum=74) writes:

> Since logic mandates that a boy be given a name only after he has entered the covenant of the bris of Avraham Avinu, why did Avraham name him before?
>
> The answer lies in [Bereishis (17,19)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8212#v=19) "And G-d said: Indeed, your wife Sarah will bear you a son, and you shall name him Yitzchok". From here we see that Avraham was commanded by G-d to name his son Yitzchok as soon as he was born, and therefore he was not able to wait until after he had circumcised him.
>
> This is what the posukim quoted in the question are saying:
>
> "And Avraham named his son who had been born to him, whom Sarah had borne to him, Yitzchok. And Avraham circumcised his son Yitzchok when he was eight days old, **as G-d had commanded him**". These last words refer to both his naming of his son immediately after he was born, and his circumcising him on the eighth day, because both things were commanded by G-d.