# Naming a baby boy before a deferred bris

Tags: names, brit-milah, psych-mentalhealth, baby-infant

The typical practice when a baby boy is born is to refrain from calling him by any name until he is given a name at his bris. In cases where the bris is deferred (e.g. for health reasons) for an extended length of time, it can be difficult--and potentially psychologically damaging--for the parents to not use a name for their child for a period of months. Is it permitted to give the child a name before his bris in such a circumstance?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there is some halakhic component to the practice you reference, rather than a mere cultural tendency. Citing a source for this would improve the question.

Answer (score 6):

Sefer Asia - [page 244](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52109&st=&pgnum=242) and [page 245](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52109&st=&pgnum=245) brings different stories quoted by Rabbi Chaim Miller of such situations. Amongst those quoted that urged giving a name prior to a Bris in order to be able to have a name to Daven for were Rabbi Yechezkel Levenstein Zatzal, The Ozorover Rabbi Zatzal, Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal, Rabbi Eliezer Man Shach Zatzal, and the Satmar Rabbi Zatzal. He mentions that The Steipler Zatzal disagreed and held one should not name prior to a Bris.

> לכבוד העורך – על דבר נתינת שם לילוד לפני הברית, ברצוני להוסיף מספר
>   עובדות של מעשה רב. שוחחתי עם אברך מבני ברק * והוא סיפר לי כי נולד לו
>   לפני מספר שנים בן חולה רח"ל ונכנס להרה"צ רבי יחזקאל לוינשטיין זצ"ל,
>   המשגיח דישיבת פוניבז' וביקש ממנו שיתפלל על בנו. הרב שאל מיד מה שמו,
>   וכשנענה שעוד לא נתנו לילד שם היות ומדובר לפני הברית, אמר מיד "והרי אין
>   על מי להתפלל !" לשאלת האברך מה עליו לעשות אמר לו הרב המשגיח זצ"ל שיסע
>   לאדמו"ר מאוזרוב בתל אביב, ויאמר לו כי יש לו בן חולה שעדיין לא נתנו לו
>   שם. נכנס אותו אברך לאדמו"ר מאוזרוב זצ"ל וסיפר לו אודות בנו. האדמו"ר
>   דרש שינתן שם לילד, ומיד עשה "מי שברך" ונתן לו שם. חזר האברך אל הרב
>   המשגיח זצ"ל, והלה אמר לו : "עכשיו יש על מי להתפלל ולבקש, כי הרי יש לנו
>   שם", וברכו : "הקב"ה יעזור והילד פב"פ יבריא". וב"ה הבן הבריא.   על מקרה
>   מיוחד שמעתי ממש בימים האחרונים. לאברך אחר מבני ברק * נולד בן חולה מאד
>   ר"ל בעת שהותו בארה"ב (לפני חודשיים), והברית נדחתה, פנה האברך לגר"מ
>   פיינשטיין שליט"א אשר פסק לקרוא לו שם מייד ולא להמתין עד לברית.   עם
>   שובו לארץ ישראל שאל בענין זה גם את הגרא"מ שך שליט"א ראש ישיבת פוניבז'
>   ואת הגר"י קניבסקי שליט"א (בעל הקהילות יעקב).   הרב שך קבע שיש לקרוא שם
>   לילוד החולה קודם הברית אלא אם כן מצבו של התינוק אנוש. לעומת זאת דעת
>   הגר"י קניבסקי שליט"א היתה להמנע מקריאת השם עד לברית.   על מקרה נוסף
>   שמעתי בהיותי השנה לאחר חג הפסח באירופה. נמסר לי כי לפני כמה שנים היה
>   מקרה של ילד שנולד חולה ונסע אבי הבן לאדמו"ר מסטמאר זצ"ל, וזה אמר לו כי
>   צריך לתת שם לילד ורק אח"כ לבוא לבקש ברכה, כי הרי כעת אין על מי לבקש.
>   בהיותי בן למוהל ידוע לי על מקרים דומים נוספים בהם נתנו שם לפני הברית,
>   וכולם בהתיעצות עם גדולי תורה ופוסקים.   בתפילה כי רופא החולים ירפא לכל
>   חולי עמו ישראל, ובברכת התורה,   הרב חיים מילר פתח תקוה

Answer (score 2):

This circumstance happened to a family in my community. The baby was born with a health problem that required deferring the bris for 6 months. Their rabbi told them to name the baby following the same procedure that is followed for baby girls, simply replacing feminine pronouns in the *mi shebeirach* with masculine ones.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seems interesting. However, IIRC, we were advised NOT to name our 1st born son until the brit which was about 4 months after he was born. (Yes, he was a "miracle" baby who's now a miracle adult. Father's biased love, no?? I'm allowed!)

The only ones confused by our policy were the non-Jewish hospital doctors and nurses. For "Mi Sheberach", we referred to him as "Hanolad".

Comment: I know a rav whose child could not have a bris for some months. In "Mi SheBeirach," he was referred to as "Tinok ben [mother's name]," but otherwise they affectionately referred to him by the nickname "Tzaddikel."

Comment: Standard minhag is to wait to name the child and refer to him as tinok.

Comment: @user6591 I think that's only standard when it's not expected to be an extremely long time (for some value of extreme)

Answer (score 1):

The reason we why we wait till the bris is to copy Hashem who gave a new name to Avraham Avinu. But technically even on the first day it is permitted

Comment: Is this your own idea, or is it sourced? (EDIT: answer to [Why did Avraham name his son before the Bris (circumcision)?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11198/5151))